# Jenkinsfile pipeline trigger stages based on git commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinfile that contains 5 stages, independent from each other.
I would like to trigger each stage based on git commit.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can trigger the stages based on the branch or tag - if that is not your use case, please provide more background information of what you are going to achieve.

Comment: @Thomas I know about branch and tags. I wanna get last commit and grep for specific string and then use when condition telling to stage run only if that string is in last commit

Answer (score 1):

You can query the changelog for specific text

```
stage("Enterprise build") {
    when {
        changelog "^make-it-so.*"
        branch "master"
    }
    steps {
        script {
            //do special stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have 2 when conditions for one stage?

Comment: Please open a separate question since the original question is answered.